@SendToUser doesn't send message to user
I have a problem. I would be very happy if someone could help me with this. My Spring server successfully receives the message and sends a message to "/queue/private-messages", but my Angular server, which is subscribed, doesn't receive it. Here's my code (I have a user with username "admin1" and ID 2)
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .requestMatchers("/user").hasRole("USER")
                        .requestMatchers("/auth/**", "/all", "/websocket/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer :: disable)
                .sessionManagement(manager -> manager.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService.userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  message: string = ''
  anotherUserMessage: string = ''
  ownMessage: string = ''
  private stompClient: any

  private jwtToken: string = 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbjEiLCJpZCI6MiwiaWF0IjoxNzE4MTE1MTY2LCJleHAiOjE3MTgxMTU3NjZ9.Hq-hU704Q7PIrOAWQSOYWPZ55lzJU2eAfSurNkdSEBc';

  constructor(private themeService: ThemeServiceService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.themeService.setTheme(this.themeService.getTheme());

    this.initConnection();
    this.join();
  }
  private initConnection() {
    const URL = '//localhost:8080/websocket'
    const socket = new SockJS(URL);
    this.stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
  }
  private join() {
    this.stompClient.connect({}, () => {
       this.stompClient.subscribe('/user/queue/private-messages', (message: any) => {
        this.anotherUserMessage = JSON.parse(message.body).content;
        console.log("FROM SERVER" + message.body)
      })
    })
  }

  public sendPrivateMessage() {
    console.log(this.message);
    this.ownMessage = this.message
    const messageJSON = {
      messageContent: this.message
    };
    this.stompClient.send('/ws/private-message', { Authorization: this.jwtToken }, JSON.stringify(messageJSON));
  }

}

@Controller
@CrossOrigin
public class WebSocketController {

    @MessageMapping("/global-message")
    @SendTo("/topic/global-messages")
    public ResponseMessage publicMessage(Message message) {
        System.out.println(message.getMessageContent());
        return new ResponseMessage("From server: " + message.getMessageContent());
    }
    @MessageMapping("/private-message")
    @SendToUser("/queue/private-messages")
    public ResponseMessage privateMessage(Message message, SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor) {
        Authentication authentication = (Authentication) headerAccessor.getUser();
        if (authentication != null && authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof UserDetails) {
            UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
            System.out.println("MESSAGE " + message.getMessageContent());
            System.out.println("Sending private message to user: " + userDetails.getUsername());

            return new ResponseMessage("Private message for user " + userDetails.getUsername() + ": " + message.getMessageContent());
        }
        return new ResponseMessage("User not found.");
    }
}


@Component
public class WebSocketChannelInterceptor implements ChannelInterceptor {
    @Autowired
    private final JwtService jwtService;
    @Autowired
    public WebSocketChannelInterceptor(JwtService jwtService) {
        this.jwtService = jwtService;
    }

    @Override
    public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
        StompHeaderAccessor accessor = MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);
        if(StompCommand.SEND.equals(accessor.getCommand())) {
            String token = accessor.getFirstNativeHeader("Authorization");
            if (token != null && token.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                token = token.substring(7);
                System.out.println(token);
                UserDetails userDetails = jwtService.loadUserByToken(token);
                if (userDetails != null) {
                    Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());


                    accessor.setUser(authentication);
                }
            }
        }
        return message;
    }
}

I tried to subscribe to the URL with userId.
      this.stompClient.subscribe('/user/2/queue/private-messages', (message: any) => {

